# AngularJS clears input fields populated with Laravel form model binding

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am new to AngularJS and i work Laravel. When i fill my input fields with Laravel form model binding, and i set `ng-model="title"` on input field, AngularJs clears populated input and sets it's value to `''`;

When i comment `ng-model="title"`, field is populated.
on page load for few miliseconds input field is populated, and i think when AngularJS initializes `$scope`, input fields become empty.

I have not any `controller` in angular and when i add angular to page this problem appears.

How can i prevent angular from clear input fields, that are filled for edit action?

Comment: Angular will clear the input-field, because $scope.title is not initialized? If you have no controller, the $scope is not available, so the variable 'title' will be also not available and its just ''.

Try implement a controller and it should work.

Comment: also you could pass your data to angular and initalize on client side. Check out this pack: https://github.com/laracasts/PHP-Vars-To-Js-Transformer

Comment: @CodeNashor i don't need to controller because my input fields are populated without AngularJS. i think there is a simple way that prevent angular form clear input fields.

Answer (score 0):

I found an good answer. we should set value, on input element via `ng-init` directive. so value will be accessible on scope and input filed will be populated:

```
<input ng-model="title" ng-init="title='{{ $title = $post->title }}'" value="{{ $title }}" type="text">
```

Now i use this solution.